# Run Xdebug on laravel sail docker Windows PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, docker, phpstorm

So, after hours of Googling no right answer is found. Ive started the Laravel 8.x tutorial installation for Windows using Docker and Laravel's sail.

Now i want to use Xdebug and have absolutely no idea what to do.

in the root of the project there is a docker-compose.yml (this is the default)

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            PHP_IDE_CONFIG: 'serverName=localhost'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            # - selenium
    # selenium:
    #     image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
    #     volumes:
    #         - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
    #     networks:
    #         - sail
    #     depends_on:
    #         - laravel.test
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${DB_PORT}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${REDIS_PORT}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
    # memcached:
    #     image: 'memcached:alpine'
    #     ports:
    #         - '11211:11211'
    #     networks:
    #         - sail
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - 1025:1025
            - 8025:8025
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

And in the vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0 folder there is a Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev \
       php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd \
       php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached \
       php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring \
       php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap \
       php8.0-intl php8.0-readline \
       php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap \
       php8.0-redis \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.0

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

now what?
I'm on a Windows system
I want to connect it to PhpStorm

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem for VS Code on a Linux workstation.

Maybe my solution could work for you, too.

Apparently, XDebug is not installed at all with Laravel Sail. In order to include it, you have to modify the `Dockerfile`, edit `docker-compose.yml` and rebuild the containers.

Here is how I did.

1. I copied the Docker configuration Laravel Sail uses in a more convenient place:

`cp -r vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0 ./resources/docker/`

2. I changed the `context` and added a variable under `args` in the first lines of `docker-compose.yml`:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./resources/docker/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
                XDEBUG: ${APP_DEBUG}

...
```

So the `context` points where I copied the original Docker configuration. I also decided to bind the new `XDEBUG` arg to the value of the `APP_DEBUG` variable inside the `.env` file, in order to switch off XDebug in a production environment.

3. Then, I changed the `Dockerfile` I copied before in order to include xdebug when building the containers. The script should also write the correct configuration options for Xdebug 3 inside `php.ini`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG XDEBUG

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev \
       php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd \
       php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached \
       php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring \
       php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap \
       php8.0-intl php8.0-readline \
       php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap \
       php8.0-redis

RUN if [ ${XDEBUG} ] ; then \
    apt-get install -y php-xdebug \
    && echo "[XDebug]" > /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini \
    && echo "zend_extension="$(find /usr/lib/php/20200930/ -name xdebug.so)" > /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini" \
    && echo "xdebug.mode = debug" >> /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.start_with_request = yes" >> /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.discover_client_host = true" >> /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini ;\
fi;

RUN php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*


RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.0

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

4. After stopping, rebuilding and relaunching the containers:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/sail stop
$ ./vendor/bin/sail up --build -d
```

You can find out if XDebug is running:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/sail php -v
PHP 8.0.0 (cli) (built: Nov 27 2020 12:26:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

**For VSCode only:**

5. Inside `Preferences -> Settings` under `Debug` you should check "Debug: Allow breakpoints everywhere".
6. Change the default `launch.json` file:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003,
      "pathMappings": {
          "/var/www/html" : "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch currently open script",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "port": 9000
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Rather than copying the original docker files, you should be able just use `php artisan sail:publish` (as per [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#sail-customization))

Comment: it's critical to insert the lines in the Dockerfile in the middle of the existing RUN command (i.e. split it into two before you add the xdebug block). Simply putting the xdebug block after it does NOT work! I spent two hours figuring that out :(

Comment: I followed these instructions and can see `sail php -v` includes xdebug...but now what? If I open VSC and run the "Listen for XDebug" (by hitting F5), then go to my terminal and run `sail test`, I get lots of errors saying `Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`

Comment: I figured it out...I added the following lines after the `discover_client_host` line: ```&& echo "xdebug.idekey = VSC" >> /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal" >> /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_port = 9003" >> /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini;```

Comment: Thank you very much, @smenzer , I will test on my configuration asap. What machine are you using? I supposed ```host.docker.internal``` would not have worked on Linux but it's the correct parameter. In fact, you need to pass the container IP on ```xdebug.client_host``` and, of course, I should not hard code it.

Comment: Before this command: apt-get install -y php-xdebug \ you must update apt-get. So, insert this: apt-get update && \

Comment: @smenzer comment was 100% needed on a Mac. PHPStorm could not connect to xdebug until I added those ini settings.

Comment: If you're on vscode : The only way I could make this work was with this setting on the launch configuration : `"hostname": "localhost"`

Answer (score 7):

There is a discarded PR for optional Xdebug 3.0 support in laravel/sail (PHP 7.4 and PHP 8). Please [follow the discussion](https://github.com/laravel/sail/pull/48).

Check the [commit](https://github.com/laravel/sail/pull/48/commits/dfae8adbaafcb2608ee905ee93a104a3e169a347), what to change in `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml.` Don't forget to set the variables in your .env

Comment: This is actually the best answer, as you just need the changes in github

Comment: If you're on vscode : The only way I could make this work was with this setting on the launch configuration : `"hostname": "localhost"`

Comment: This answer would be more complete with : add ```services: laravel.test: extra_hosts: - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"``` (for linux users) Furthermore it's not in discussion nor in commit messages... See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/4726998

Answer (score 6):

I got XDebug to work with a web request after some help from the posters above.

I have quite a bit of experience with PHPStorm and XDebug 2.x.  I am new to docker so there may be better ways to fix this.  <s>I have not yet figured out how to run or debug tests that rely on the database connection from inside PHPStorm (right click on a test to debug). They run successfully with breakpoints if I am "listening" to `sail test` (which will run the tests correctly) but PHPStorm can't find the MySQL database when running tests and I also get this error: "Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003"</s>

Update 1/18/21 to fix local environment within PHPStorm so that it can find the database and the rest of the Docker network.  Now I can successfully run tests and debug from within PHPStorm.  With the current build of PHPStorm 2020.3.1 You need to add the network *name* where it asks for the network *mode*.  I will be reporting this to them so it may get addressed soon.

Get your network name by running `docker network ls`.  In this case it is myProjectName_sail.

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                             DRIVER    SCOPE
8e8635ce01a6   bridge                           bridge    local
401307dbfaad   host                             host      local
ad8020ad629e   myProjectName_sail               bridge    local
d85a9668cade   none                             null      local
```

Enter this in PHPStorm Preferences>PHP>CLI Interpreter>...

[image]

On to the fix for debugging web requests:

What I have:

- Laravel Sail version 8.0
- Xdebug version 3.0
- PHPStorm version 2020.3 The version of PHPStorm is important as it supports PHP8 and Xdedbug 3.

What I did:

- I installed vim in my docker container by adding this line to the Dockerfile: `RUN apt-get -y install vim`
- This lets me view/edit files easily by running
  `docker exec -it mySite.test_1 vim /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini`.
- In this case I still edited the Dockerfile  to generate the php.ini

You need to get your `/etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini` file to look like this (client_host was the key):

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal
```

I added this to the Dockerfile as recommended by @Enea74.  I was having trouble getting the conditional to return TRUE so I hard coded `TRUE` here for now:

```
RUN if [ true ] ; then \
    apt-get install -y php-xdebug \
    && echo "[XDebug]" > /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini \
    && echo "zend_extension="$(find /usr/lib/php/20200930/ -name xdebug.so)" > /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini" \
    && echo "xdebug.mode = debug" >> /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.start_with_request = yes" >> /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal" >> /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini ;\
fi;
```

- I built the Docker containers by running `sail build --no-cache`
- then `sail up -d`

`sail php -v`
returns:

```
PHP 8.0.0 (cli) (built: Nov 27 2020 12:26:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

Now In PHPStorm do the following.  I think that it discovered many of these settings on its own: I don't remember setting all of these values:

[image: Add CLI Interpreters for Sail]

[image: Validate Xdebug Installation]

[image: setting up docker]

Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: You may have forgotten to declare ARG XDEBUG on line 6 on the Dockerfile.
That's why it isn't interpreted.

Comment: This is the best guide I've found. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 1):

The underlying dockerfile can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.0/Dockerfile).

<s>In order to run xdebug you need to install the PHP extension.
Personally I like to use [docker-php-extension-installer](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) to install them.</s>

Add these lines after line 35:

```
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/master/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions xdebug
```

Add these lines after line 35:

```
RUN sudo apt-get install php-xdebug
```

After that you need to configure Xdebug, PhpStorm and your browser.

1. configure xdebug to connect to you host machine

**xdebug.ini**

```
    zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so
    
    xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
    xdebug.remote_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_autostart=1
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

both the [remote_port](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html) and the [remote_host](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/) are very important.
Make sure this port does not conflict with a service inside the container, in this case do **not** use [8000](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.0/Dockerfile#L47) as PHP already runs on this port.

2. configure PhpStorm

You need to create a server first under:

File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Servers

[image]

It is very important to correctly map the paths in this case:
[.:/var/www/html](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/stubs/docker-compose.yml#L16)

Which means your project root directory on the left should map to `/var/www/html`

Now it is time to create a run config. You can do this in the top right corner of PhpStorm under "Add Configuration..."

[image]

Use the screenshot as a guide.

3. lastly start the debug session in the browser, easiest way is to use the chrome extension [Xdebug helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc). Change the IDE key as configured earlier under settings and left click the extension icon > debug to start debugging.

Also do the same inside PhpStorm in the right corner.
[image]

Comment: Doesn't work - "'The script is meant to be used with official Docker PHP Images". The Docker service isn't based on the official PHP images, so the `install-php-extensions` script fails to execute.

Comment: Well that means we have to install xdebug the hard way: https://gist.github.com/henryonsoftware/066d8282daaf8c2ae281ce010e3e5404

Comment: @onlineThomas thank you for the detailed instructions but i too have the error "'The script is meant to be used with official Docker PHP Images". the hard way is a little hard for me to understand :(

Comment: Apparently I made a mistake to assume that the install script would also work on this container. That's why you need the new instructions above to install xdebug by hand on Ubuntu (as it is an Ubuntu based image)

Comment: @onlineThomas i think i almost got it. I needed to use the php7.4 sail instead of the 8.0 and added php7.4-xdebug in the list of apt-get install modules instead of on a seperate line. Now xdebug also shows in the phpinfo() file. Only thing is: i dont know is where to put the xdebug.ini file. Is it in the root of the project? There is still no incomming connection. Also ive mapped the 9000 port to the phpstorm settings. but still no connection

Comment: and.. do i need to change anything in this line?     xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal

Comment: @RuudvandeVen You need to map xdebug.ini to the path in your container using docker-compose volumes (path is `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/`). You don't have to change anything in that line.

Answer (score 1):

My contribution to @Enea74 and @smenzer great answers above:

I successfully configured Sail with xdebug working on VSCODE on linux mint.

But when I run some phpUnit or sail test, it was not working as expected and received this message

> Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9000 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

After a long search, I figured out that need to add this line on the Dockerfile of Sail after the apt install commands:

> RUN ip -4 route list match 0/0 | awk '{print $3 " host.docker.internal"}' >> /etc/hosts

Rebuild the containers with

> sail down

> sail up --build --force-recreate -d

And then the xdebug start to work with phpunit tests on shell along with normal browser navigation.

Note: if the command 'ip' is not working, add the package 'iproute2' on previous apt install commands.

Comment: #18 147.5 /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/hosts: Read-only file system
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug     && apt update     && apt install iproute2 -y     && ip -4 route list match 0/0 | awk '{print
 $3 " host.docker.internal"}' >> /etc/hosts]: exit code: 2
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation as OP and didn't find a solution, but this is what I found:

If you've installed xdebug via command line recently, chances are you've installed Xdebug V3 which has different config options than Xdebug V2. It doesn't have remote_autostart or remote_enable options so setting those will have no effect.

You can read more about Xdebug 3 config options here: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings